# React native Auth flow + redux state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, react-native-navigation

I am building a react native app, I am using react-native navigation-6 with protected routes but when I start the app I get this error, I can't figure out why it's not seeing the redux store provided.

redux is set up well and I use it in the app for other things.

[image]

```
    export default function App() {
      const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
    
      const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <StatusBar animated={true} barStyle='light-content' />
            <PaperProvider>
              <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator
                  initialRouteName='Login'
                  headerMode='screen'
                  options={{
                    headerTitle: (props) => (
                      <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
                        <DropDown
                          label={'Gender'}
                          mode={'outlined'}
                          value={category}
                          setValue={setCategory}
                          list={menuList}
                          visible={showDropDown}
                          showDropDown={() => setShowDropDown(true)}
                          onDismiss={() => setShowDropDown(false)}
                          inputProps={{
                            right: <TextInput.Icon name={'menu-down'} />,
                          }}
                        />
                      </View>
                    ),
    
                    headerStyle: {
                      backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
                    },
                    headerTintColor: '#fff',
                    headerTitleStyle: {
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                    },
                  }}
                >
                  {isLoggedIn ? (
                    <>
                      <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
                      <Stack.Screen
                        name='comments'
                        component={CommentsFeed}
                      />
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <>
                      <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login} />
                      <Stack.Screen name='Register' component={Register} />
                    </>
                  )}
                </Stack.Navigator>
              </NavigationContainer>
            </PaperProvider>
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`App` must be wrapped in provider since you are using `useSelector` in it.

```
export default function Wrapper(){ 
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>  
      <App />  
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

app

```
export default function App() {
      const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
    
      const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
    
      return ( 
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <StatusBar animated={true} barStyle='light-content' />
              .....
```